# Woocommerce category description using shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to replace the Woocommerce category description on pages using a shortcode.

With the shortcode I want to dynamically display custom featured image and description for current category.

Here is some code I found from searching here and Google. This code seemed to work but also affected single product pages.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this please ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', function ($description) {
    if (! is_product_category()) { return; }   
    return do_shortcode('[porto_block id="510079"]');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following conditions to make sure it only works on category pages.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', function ($description) {
    if ( is_product_category() && !is_single() && !is_product()) {    
        return do_shortcode('[porto_block id="510079"]');
    }else{
        return $description;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this on single product page please. Replacing short description. Thank you so much

Comment: Code goes in your `functions.php` file of your theme. That's how you use it.